# Mod_rewrite .htaccess problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

I'm having some trouble with a .htaccess file I'm using, I think the issue is with the conditions & rules I'm using as examples I have used have worked properly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*ts$|.*m3u8$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) process.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

If anyone can spot the mistake and point me in the write direction I'd be most grateful.

Thanks

Comment: What's problem with this?

Comment: It doesn't work at all it acts as if there are no rewrite rules. If I remove the 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*ts$|.*m3u8$ [NC]' line then it loads process.php however the 'file' $_GET doesn't work.

Comment: What URL are you sending to web sever?

Comment: For example http://myip/folder/stream.m3u8 which should load http://myip/folder/process.php?file=stream.m3u8 but instead just says stream.m3u8 cannot be found.

Comment: Remove `RewriteCond` and change rule to this: `RewriteRule ^.*\.(?:ts|m3u8)$ process.php?file=$0 [NC,L,QSA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*\.(?:ts|m3u8)$ process.php?file=$0 [NC,L,QSA]
```